# What means 'Conflicting access is here' warning(?) in Swift

Tags: swift

A piece of code in Swift generates the following strange error (in red) and warning(?) (in grey):

[image: Clousere that generates Error]

As I can not find a description of this error/warning(?), I intuitively introduced the local variable as suggested. Result: the error disappeared, but the warning(?) remained:

[image: Annoying warrning]

Still no description of what it means.

Can anyone help me understand the warning(?) and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Please include code as text, not images. See [ask]

Comment: I don't have Xcode in front of me so can't test this, but warnings sometimes linger when they should go away; is it still there if you close and reopen your project? For what it's worth, if you're mutating your struct a lot, you're probably better off with a class (for performance, style, and simplicity).

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/memorysafety/

Comment: @jnpdx I have presented the image to reproduce the strange warning in grey instead of the usual yellow. The code as a text would not allow me that. Anyway, thank you for a remark.

Comment: Generally, the approach is to either include the actual text and images together or include the errors as comments inside the text. The images you've included are blurry and cannot be copied/pasted, searched, or read by a screen reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `self.selectedIds` inside of a closure while in the middle of mutating `self`. This isn't allowed. During the call to a mutating function, nothing else is allowed to access the struct.

The error includes the solution, which is a local copy of `selectedIds`. The easiest way to do that is with a capture list:

```
discardAll(where: { [selectedIds] in selectedIds.contains($0.id)})
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes a copy of `selectedIds` for the closure, so `self` is not required inside the closure.

Another approach is to make a manual copy. This is effectively identical to the above approach:

```
let selectedIdsCopy = selectedIds
discardAll(where: { selectedIdsCopy.contains($0.id)})
```